# example server/client code in C++ (not C)

Tags: c++, client-server, boost-asio

I'm trying to find a server/client implementation in C++ on the web.

I found dozens of implementations written in C (not C++) - just like [this one](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

How about something in c++?

Is [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) the only alternative to pure C - or am I missing some libraries?

Comment: What's wrong with boost::asio? Have a look at the more resent version 1.52 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Comment: What's wrong with wrapping the c functions with your own class?  Or, for that matter, what's wrong with just calling the c functions from c++ code?

Comment: @Goz: You could wrap it with your own class. But why when it has already been done (reinventing the wheel is not that interesting). You could just call the C functions. But why when you can use the extra power of C++ (RAII/Exceptions) to make a better interface that is easier to use.

Comment: @LokiAstari I totally agree I was mainly questioning why it needs a c++ interface ... I wrote my own ultra lightweight wrapper that gives me full IP address handling as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find plenty of C++ examples in Qt's documentation of the QtNetwork module. They even have a specialized class to act as a TCP server, which is aptly named [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtcpserver.html).

You will also find more complete examples there :

- [Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/network-fortuneserver.html)
- [Threaded Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/network-threadedfortuneserver.html)
- [Loopback Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/network-loopback.html)
- [Torrent Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/network-torrent.html)